# Remove a nail-in box with 3 romex cables and not cut drywall?

Tags: junction-box, removal

Single gang nail-in box for thermostat was about 1" recessed and probably too small for 3 romex cables of 10g wire. Orig. installer 30 years ago left 1.5 inches of sheathing on all cables. Extension boxes I bought were too small, so I thought I'd just replace box with a bigger one and bring it forward...

Cut box nails.Thought I would cut out box with dremel flex shaft but it isn't working...friend suggested Multitool but I can't see how a any size blade could get in there. Suggestions?

Comment: "*friend suggested Multitool*" What multi-tool?  "*but I can't see how a round blade could get in there.*" Neither can we, We can not see anything. Photos and using complete sentences with more detailed descriptions will help to provide an informed answer. (*I would like to buy an I, Please, MR Sajak.*)

Comment: Said you were able to remove nails from studs.  Are you trying to use nails to replace box to stud?  Try using screws, if replacement box has holes on inside.

Comment: It sounds like you're replacing the Tstat with something else or why would you run 10 guage wire?  If you mean the outer jacket of the cables extends 1.5" into the box why would that be a problem if you're removing the box anyway?  Just cut back the sheathing as necessary when you install the new box.

Comment: The exact type of box and how it's mounted matters too.  Some types of box you can bash or pry welds or joins apart to disassemble the box before you even try to remove it, but only if it's very securely mounted.  If you're trying to cut the nails with the dremel, the box is probably too narrow for any of the bits that would do it quickly.  Sometimes for awkward cuts like that I take a 32 tpi hacksaw blade and just wield it barehanded, but it's easier to cut a nail when it's still in the stud. Many types of nail are fairly soft so you may be able to cut them with long head wire cutters too.

Comment: @KH it could be a 240V  thermostat.

Comment: empty cavity or insulated?

Comment: I was listing my reasons for replacing the box: too small, too much sheathing, recessed 1" in wall, (didn't mention full of old paint). I am replacing an old 240v thermostat on 30 amp breaker. Cavity is empty. Nails are already cut. Box is gray plastic and sorry I can't get a pic on here.

Comment: definitely place pics help. more word. complete sentence. i thought box metal. answer say palstic.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the box making two surgical cuts with a dremel tool and cutting attachment (not going too close to wires). Then i broke the plastic the remaining distance. Twisted and pulled the box out.

Answer (score 0):

after releasing the wires and having attached strings to retrieve them (if needed)

flip it around and remove the clamps, then flip it backwards and sideways, crush it using multi-grips, then align the short side of the pancaked box with the long axis of the hole and pull it through.